# Trex Traffic generator in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, packet, cisco, network-traffic

I'm relatively new to cloud and T-rex. I was trying to do a simple loopback on a `c5.4xlarge` instance on AWS

I did the following:

- Built Trex on Aamazon Linux 2 AMI
- Attached 2 additional interfaces to the instance (`10.0.1.103`) residing on subnet A and (`10.0.2.96`) residing on subnet B

I wanted to test a simple loop back using trex:

- In `dpdk_setup_ports.py`, I selected the 2 interfaces and went with ip based configuration and defaults `1.1.1.1` and gateway `2.2.2.2` and vice versa for the second interface
- Ran trex server in promiscuous mode (`./t-rex-64 -i -c 2 --prom`)
- In another terminal I ran `./trex-console` and ran the `bench.py` file (I had made changes in the `bench.py` file, the start and end for src address was `10.0.1.103` and dest was `10.0.2.96`)
- Ran it for single port i.e 0 (traffic flow 0->1)

I was able to pump the traffic, but was not able to receive it.

I had added a Route Table saying target `10.0.0.0/16 dest=interface of 10.0.2.96`  and target `0.0.0.0/0 dest=interface of 10.0.2.96`

According to this, any packet leaving subnet A should go to the interface of `10.0.2.96` which is in subnet B and for security groups, I have added a rule to allow all packets and ip addresses, but was still not able to receive any packets on the other interface.

Any help would be appreciated.

I allowed all traffic in the security groups, and I double checked my routing table, it was fine itself.